# Can we eat fast food?

Tags: quran, hadith

Allah says in the Quran:
(2:195) Spend in the Way of Allah and do not cast yourselves into destruction with your own hands; do good, for Allah loves those who do good.
Fast food is harmful for our health, so is it ok to eat fast food?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Excess of everything is bad. You can eat anything as long as it is halal.

Comment: https://youtu.be/n5D1D_zqasE here is a link of video to support my answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: If you are satisfied with answer kindly mark as answered.